# Formatear una cantidad numérica a 5 digitos

Tags: php, formato

Necesito imprimir en pantalla con PHP una cantidad numérica que siempre esté expresada en 5 dígitos, por ejemplo si la cantidad es 23 debe expresarse como 00023, si la cantidad es 200 se debe expresar como 00200, no encuentro la forma, puede ser obtener dicha cantidad desde MYSQL o puede ser mediante PHP.
¿Alguna orientación? Gracias

Comment: Ver manual de PHP, [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). `echo str_pad($el_numero, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: funcionó, muchas gracias